# How to make a discord bot that gives members a nickname (their username but in lowercases) if they have a uppercase in their username

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is what I tried, im new in programming so if someone can help me it would be great.

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is Online!')

@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after): 
    u = username
    if u:
        if u.upper()
         await after.edit(nick=username.lower)
```

Comment: `u = username` doesn't make sense... Where's `username` defined? And you probably want to indent `await after.edit(nick=username.lower)` into the if-statement

Comment: You are almost there! There's just some minor mistakes: `if u.upper()` does nothing and it has a syntax error (should have a colon at the end). You also need to __call__ `username.lower`, meaning, put `()` at the end.

Comment: That aside, I'm not sure you are doing what you describe you want to do: do you need to change a member's nickname when they themselves change it and use an uppercase? Or do that for all members that join the server? In that case you'd need to add an `on_member_join` callback.

Comment: What I try to make is a bot that gives members nicknames, because I have server where I want that all members only have lowercase letters in their name. So I want to create a bot that gives the members with a uppercase in their username a nickname with the same username but in lowercases

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are close, but not quite there: `username` is not gonna be defined in your code, and you have a few syntax errors. I'd recommend using some IDE that highlights these mistakes, especially if you are gonna make a big bot. Regarding your specific function, I'd say you need the following:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after): 
    username = after.nick
    await after.edit(nick=username.lower())
```

or if you only want to edit the nick if needed, to save on packages and not spam the server as much:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after): 
    username = after.nick
    if username != username.lower():
        await after.edit(nick=username.lower())
```

That being said, this will only update the nicks of members that change their nick to something while in the server. You might want to add the same functionality to `on_member_join` and maybe even do a single pass over all existing members.

PS: I'm not sure about `@client_event`, I'll just take that as valid from your code.